# Confusion with Wheatstone bridge resistor terminology in datasheets

Tags: datasheet, wheatstone-bridge

An off-shelf instrumentation amplifier manual has the following indication for Rb:
[image]

And [this](http://www.shr-etest.com/upload/product/201812/10/201812101701087238.pdf) force-transducer gives the following resistance parameter:
[image]

I guess Rb is each single resistor value of the Wheatstone bridge.

But what could be meant by input resistance and output resistance regarding the force-transducer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *But what could be meant by input resistance and output resistance
>   regarding the force-transducer?*

If the data sheet said input resistance was 350 ohm and output resistance was 350 ohm, I don't think you'd have much worry about that because, 4 x 350 ohms in a bridge gives you that equal input and output resistance. But, when the input resistance is quoted as higher than the output resistance, it makes you think. It's not entirely a guess (because I've come across it before in pressure bridges) but, I believe that extra resistance is due to temperature compensation like this: -

[image]

Picture of [4-arm Wheatstone bridge with temperature compensation](https://www.vishay.com/thermistors/ntc/design-support-tool/four-arm-wheatstone-bridge/).

So, from the point of view of the battery, it sees \$R_G+R_C\$. That's the input resistance. The output resistance remains unchanged at \$R_G\$.

Comment: Interesting. I understand how input impedance is affected by Rs above. But couldnt derive the output(Thevenin) resistance in this case mostly because there is no ground at the output terminals. But I think it would be a different question.

Comment: Well, if Vcc was open circuit the output Z would be (\$R_G+R_G\$)||(\$R_G+R_G\$) = \$R_G\$. And, if you think about it, when sorting Vcc out it's just the same.

Comment: But to find Thevenin output impedance dont we short the independent voltage source Vcc in this case and look from the output terminals?

Comment: It's the same resistance whether Vcc is shorted or not when the bridge is balanced.